# Laravel: Querying dynamically Time expressions

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

In order to list all the articles (films) that are included in our catalog the current month I have written the following query using the Laravel:

```
    $current_month_film = DB::table('films')
        ->join('categories', 'films.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('films.*', 'categories.*')
        ->whereMonth('films.created_at', '=', '12')
        ->orderBy('films.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

It works perfect. It shows 5 films were added this month. The only problem is that I am hard coding December (month = 12). Next month I will need to update to month = 1. And so on each month; that is a bad solution.

The questions are:

1- How could I get always the current month? Trying

`->whereMonth('films.created_at', '=', 'NOW')`

give back not error, but the list comes empty. In December there are 5 films added.

2- I am showing a message in front end:

```
5 films added in Month 12
```

Is there a way to change the month = 12 into December and show a friendlier message like:

```
5 films added in December"
```

3- A better approach would be to show films included within the last 30 days. I did not find a time function for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to utilise [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs) which comes by default with Laravel.

1. `->whereMonth('films.created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->month)`
2. Since you know `$month` = 12, you can do something like

   ```
   $someDate = Carbon::parse("2016" . $month . "01"); //someDate is a Carbon object now
   $output = "added in Month " . $someDate->format('F');
   ```
3. Retrieve data 1 month old:

   ```
   ->whereBetween('films.created_at', [Carbon::today()->subMonth(), Carbon::today()])`
   ```

Edit: Put in `use Carbon;` before your `class SomeClassName {`. You might want to read up about [Namespace](https://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/)

Comment: If only the month number is needed, `date('m')` is sufficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "it comes by default in Laravel? I get an error stating "class Carbon not found". I still need to write the class and each of the methods to get what I want right?

Comment: `use Carbon\Carbon;` on top most of your file - well, around Laravel's `use`

Comment: @STeD I don't get how to use the answer "2. Carbon::now()->format('F');" in order to show "films from December" in the front end instead "month 12". Could you please could explain what do you mean?